# How can I change the title of a group of buttons with an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

- I have two IBAction groups with three buttons each.
- Each button has a different tag - within each group: 1, 2 and 3.
- I have three arrays, with three values each.

I want to press the first button of the first IBAction and change the title of the three buttons in the second IBAction, based on the group of arrays.

Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var firstArray = ["A1","A2","A3"]
var secondArray = ["B1","B2","B3"]
var thirdArray = ["C1","C2","C3"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func greenButtons(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 1 {
        //change the title of the grayButtons with the firstArray         
}
    if sender.tag == 2 {
        //change the title of the grayButtons with the secondArray         
}
    if sender.tag == 3 {
        //change the title of the grayButtons with the thirdArray         
}

}

@IBAction func grayButtons(_ sender: UIButton) {
}

}
```

Comment: Do you have an outlet to the `grayButtons` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
// create outlet group for each
@IBOutlet weak var greenButtons:[UIButton]! 
@IBOutlet weak var grayButtons:[UIButton]!
```

Inside action of greenButtons

```
grayButtons.forEach { $0.setTitle(firstArray[$0.tag - 1],for:.normal) }
```

Instead of if check you can construct the array as

```
let allArr = [  ["A1","A2","A3"],  ["B1","B2","B3"],["C1","C2","C3"]]
```

Then

```
grayButtons.forEach { $0.setTitle(allArr[sender.tag - 1][$0.tag - 1],for:.normal) }
```

Comment: I tried this answer and the previous one that you put. For some reason is putting all the titles on the grayButtons with the same title, instead of A1, A2 and A3, one on each button. What could be happening?

Comment: I re-did everything from scratch and it worked. Not sure what was happening, but it works fine now. Thanks!